# Помощь в изменении регулярного выражения PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Есть регулярное выражение на замену BBCode в тексте:

```
$patterns = array(
'#\[b\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/b\]#s',
'#\[u\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/u\]#s',
'#\[strike\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/strike\]#s',
'#\[em\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/em\]#s',
'#\[red\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/red\]#s',
'#\[green\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/green\]#s',
'#\[yellow\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/yellow\]#s',
);

$replacements = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<u>$1</u>',
'<strike>$1</strike>',
'<em>$1</em>',
'<red>$1</red>',
'<green>$1</green>',
'<yellow>$1</yellow>',
);

$text = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

Не подскажете, как сделать так, что если поступил пустой BBCode, к примеру, `[b][/b]`, то не выводился бы пустой текст, как сейчас, а чтобы вывелся неизмененный код, то есть `"[b][/b]text"`?

Comment: Так поменяйте все `(.*?)` на `(.+?)`.

Comment: @Visman вы меня опередили :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```
$text = 'Белеет парус одинокий в тумане моря [b][/b]голубом.';

$patterns = array(
'~\[b]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/b]~s',
'~\[u]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/u]~s',
'~\[strike]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/strike]~s',
'~\[em]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/em]~s',
'~\[red]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/red]~s',
'~\[green]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/green]~s',
'~\[yellow]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/yellow]~s',
);

$replacements = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<u>$1</u>',
'<strike>$1</strike>',
'<em>$1</em>',
'<red>$1</red>',
'<green>$1</green>',
'<yellow>$1</yellow>',
);

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```