# Создание своих BB кодов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

1) способ: Как сделать всё одним регулярным выражением, а не создавать кучу переменных?

```
$str = 'hello [b]world[/b] test';

$bbFfom = preg_replace('#\[b\]#', '<b>', $str);
$bbBefore = preg_replace('#\[/b\]#', '</b>', $bbFfom);

echo $bbBefore;
```

2) способ: Я не знаю, как вставить нужное содержимое

```
$str = 'hello [b]world[/b] test';
echo preg_replace('#\[b\].+\[/b\]#', '<b>world</b>', $str);
```

Comment: Такие вещи делают не регулярками

Comment: Почему? А чем тогда?

Comment: Сюда загляните https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/733943/186083 Там в вопросе и ответе есть примеры регулярных выражений для бб-кодов. 2 массива + 1 preg_replace.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу небольшой примерчик. Данный код НЕ предназначен для работы в "боевом" проекте, во всяком случае без серьезной доработки. Код лишь показывает возможность и идею.

```
<?php
    $ebb_params = array (
        'b' => array (
                'recursive' => true,
                'function' => 'ebb_code'
            ),
        's' => array (
                'recursive' => true,
                'function' => 'ebb_code'
            ),
        'quote' => array (
                'recursive' => true,
                'function' => 'ebb_code_quote'
            ),
        'code' => array (
                'recursive' => false,
                'function' => 'ebb_code_code'
            )
    );

    function ebb_parse($text)
    {    
        return preg_replace_callback('~\\[([a-zA-Z]+)\\](.*?)\\[/(\\1)\\]~s', 'ebb_tag_matches_replace', $text);
    }

    function ebb_tag_matches_replace($match)
    {
        global $ebb_params;
        $tag = strtolower($match[1]);
        if (!isset($ebb_params[$tag])) {
            return "[$match[1]]" . ebb_parse($match[2]) . "[/$match[1]]";
        }
        $content = $match[2];
        if ($ebb_params[$tag]['recursive'] === true) {
            $content = ebb_parse($content);
        }
        return call_user_func($ebb_params[$tag]['function'], $content, $tag);
    }



    function ebb_code($content, $tag)
    {
        return "<$tag>$content</$tag>";
    }


    function ebb_code_quote($content, $tag)
    {
        return "<div style='background-color: grey;'>$content</div>";
    }


    function ebb_code_code($content, $tag)
    {
        return "<br><pre style='border: 1px solid blue'>code title<br>$content</pre>";
    }


    $str = "dsfd[quote][x]Цитата внутри не зарегистрированного тега [x] с вкраплениями [b]жирного[/b] и [s]зачеркнутого[/s] текста[/x][/quote][code][b]Какой-то код, в котором теги не[/b] раскрываются[/code]sddssd";
    echo ebb_parse($str);
?>
```